# How to I get my application to reference a dll instead of X.dll

Tags: c++, dll, c++builder

I am trying to deploy an application to a target machine and am getting a side-by-side configuration error.  I traced it and found that the application is trying to reference AxisMediaControl.X.dll instead of AxisMediaControl.dll.  I recently converted to a new version of Embarcadero (10 Seattle) and assume I've missed something in my config.  Let me know how I can remove this extra X in the filename in the reference path.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I forgot on this project I created a custom manifest file....I must include that manifest file with the deployment.  It's always tough coming back from Christmas break.  Problem solved.